# Understanding Annonations in Eclipse Editor

Tags: java, eclipse, markers

I am trying to learn Eclipse editor annonations from this site:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-eclipse-plugin-guide

It seems a preety good tutorial, but any code that I copied to my eclipse workspace, it shows always error "multiple marker in one line"

For example, when I copy the following code:

```
public static IMarker createMarker(IResource res)
throws CoreException {
       IMarker marker = null;
       //note: you use the id that is defined in your plugin.xml
       marker = res.createMarker("com.ibm.mymarkers.mymarker");
       marker.setAttribute("description," "this is one of my markers");
       //note: you can also use attributes from your supertype
       marker.setAttribute(IMarker.MESSAGE, "My Marker");
       return marker;
}
```

I will get the error that multiple markers in one line. Can you please help me regards this? I am really frustrated with it and already spent 2 hours after it.

Comment: Click on the actual error messages and try to resolve them. May be all the relevant imports are missing etc.. BTW "multiple marker in one line" implies there are multiple errors in a single line.

Comment: You are not talking about Java annotations. I have edited your question to avoid the confusion.

Comment: I am actually learning annonations in Java from that tutorial to make an eclipse plugin to highlight texts but I am facing difficulties to follow the tutorial properly as examples codes are not working properly in my eclipse. @marko topolnik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Multiple markers** means that **there is more than one thing wrong with the line specified**.
I will be assuming the error is in this line:

```
marker.setAttribute("description," "this is one of my markers");
```

Note the misplaced comma (,) corrected version should be:

```
marker.setAttribute("description", "this is one of my markers");
```

Try it out and do a clean build. I am sure it will work this time.

Comment: You are right. This tutorial has many problems and fixing that comma just solved problem in one line. However, I just noticed that he did not define many classes for which he used the concept of polymorphism.

Comment: @Newbie23 Glad to help! Mark it as answer if you are done! :)

Answer (score 0):

Hover over the error marker on the left or open the "Problems View" to see the individual errors.

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for the instructions. I did not used it before.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: His question can mean both. But my guess, since he's a  beginner, is that the example code has bugs and he wants to see all the errors.

Comment: @Aaron Digulla : Exactly